# Writing c-style string to text file and returning information from text file

Tags: arrays, char, c-strings

I'm trying to write a program that creates a structure for student info, has an array with 4 students info, writes the info to a text file, and returns the information back from the text file. I'm also supposed to do the same process with binary I/O, but that part works well so I took it out of the code. My issue is with the text file. I believe the issue is with the name part of the array. I also have the guideline to follow: "Do not use the string class in your struct definition.  Instead, use the old c-style string (i.e. array of char)" I can't figure out how to get the program to step over the space between first/last names. This is the code I have written:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

/* structure */
struct studentInfo
{
    char name[40];
    int age;
    float gpa;
    char grade;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    const int SIZE = 4;
    int i;

    /* array */
    studentInfo student[SIZE]{ {"Ann Annson\0", 10, 1.10, 'D'},
                               {"Bill Billson\0", 20, 2.20, 'C'},
                               {"Carl Carlson\0", 30, 3.30, 'B'},
                               {"Don Donson\0", 40, 4.00, 'A'} };

    /* open & write to file in text mode i/o */
    fstream fFile;
    fFile.open("students.txt", ios::out);
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        fFile << student[i].name << endl;
        fFile << student[i].age << endl;
        fFile << student[i].gpa << endl;
        fFile << student[i].grade << endl;
    }
    fFile.close();

    /* open and read information from files to new arrays */

    studentInfo studentsText[4];
    fFile.open("students.txt", ios::in);
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        fFile >> studentsText[i].name;
        fFile >> studentsText[i].age;
        fFile >> studentsText[i].gpa;
        fFile >> studentsText[i].grade;
    }
    fFile.close();

    /* display the information from students.txt */

    cout << "This is the data contained in students.txt: " << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        cout << studentsText[i].name << "\t" << studentsText[i].age;
        cout << "\t" << studentsText[i].gpa << "\t" << studentsText[i].grade << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

this is the output that I receive when I run the program:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN4Rs.png)

and this is the output I'm trying to get:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJhTD.png)

I do know that it is an issue regarding the space, because if I run the program with the spaces between the names in the array removed it returns this output: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhWo5.png)

Forgive me if this is a poor question, I'm in my first semester of c++ and I hope that I worded this well for anyone that attempts to help. Thank you to everyone who looks at this and tries to help!

*side note*
[this](https://pastebin.com/V9aQeRff) is the full code I have written
and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlWSq.png) is the output I receive when running that code

Comment: There is a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476668/reading-string-with-spaces-in-c